# There's a way to recover a card location?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I'm trying the recover the location of a card previously set, so I could replace the HTML card with a map and a route with Glass last location.
But when I get the card back, it has no location. The location is set on card because I tested on Glass and it's all right.
Here's my piece of PHP code:

```
 elseif ($user_action['type'] == 'CUSTOM' && $user_action['payload'] == 'show-in-map')
  {
      $timeline_item_id = $request['itemId'];

      $timeline_item = $mirror_service->timeline->get($timeline_item_id);

      $patch = new Google_TimelineItem();

      $cardFomater = new Card_Formater($patch->getHtml());

      $cardLocation = $timeline_item->getLocation();

      $patch->setHtml($cardFomater->replaceHtmlWithMap($location->getLatitude(),$location->getLongitude(),
          $cardLocation->getLatitude(),$cardLocation->getLongitude()));

      $mirror_service->timeline->patch($timeline_item_id, $patch);
  }
```

It says the $cardLocation does not have the property getLatitude().

Comment: Did you glassware originally set the location on this timeline card?

Comment: Yes, from query on spatial database.
The card has location, and it works on Glass.